# How can we add a second Cassandra DC running in a separate Openshift/Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, openshift, bitnami

We deployed 2 cassandra datacenters in 2 different openshift clusters (one for each openshift cluster).
Each cassandra datacenter has one seed pod (pod-0)

We used bitnami helm-chart ( https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/cassandra)

Now we would like to connect both cassandra datacentres in order to synchronize the data.
How can we do it?

I suppose that we need to expose Cassandra traffic using an openshift route. But which port and service to expose/use?

I can see that we have:

- a service called myrelease-cassandra, type ClusterIP, targeting 9042/TCP (cql)
- a service called myrelease-cassandra-headless, Headless(no ip), targeting 7000/TCP (intra), 7001/TCP (tls),7199/TCP (jmx),9042/TCP (cql)

I tried a couple of solution but so far I didn't succeed:
for example I can see from the logs that the Cassandra rings are trying to connect over the port 9042, but the Openshift routes are accessible through the port 443:

- if I set the external seed (basically the other openshift cluser route) with the port number (e.g. my-os-route:443) I see errors saying: host could not be resolved.
- if I do not set the port number I see a timeout because the port is 9042 instead of 443

we configured cassandra to use ssl, and the routes in openshift are accessible thorugh an F5 loadbalancer which targets all the infra nodes of opsnhift

**UPDATE 1**

Basically we would like to replicate this architecture (but with 2 k8s clusters and without the operator)
https://itnext.io/managing-a-multi-site-cassandra-cluster-on-multiple-kubernetes-with-casskop-multicasskop-cf407c297701

or
https://docs.k8ssandra.io/components/k8ssandra-operator/

**UPDATE 2**

Basically if there would be a way to configure the intra node port as 7000 but saying to cassandra to use another port to connect to other cassandra hosts it would work.
Something like Elasticsearch where you have `http.port` and `http.publish_port` [Elasticsearch configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#http-settings)

Comment: Which version of Cassandra are you using?  If it's pre-4.0, you'll want to make sure port 7001 is open (internode SSL).  Otherwise both SSL and non-SSL are done over 7000 (by default) in 4.0+.

Comment: When you write that you 'want to connect them', if these are bootstrapped as 2 separate clusters, you can not join/merge them.

Comment: @Andrew I mean that we would like to replicate what you see here https://docs.k8ssandra.io/components/k8ssandra-operator/ (unfortunately we cannot use the operator). I will add more info in the main post as well

Comment: @Aaron we are using cassandra 4+.  We are on openshift/kubernetes, when you mean the port 7000 has to be open you mean that it has to be reachable ourside the cluster with an openshift route?

Comment: The two DCs will need port 7000 open/routed between them.  Also @Andrew is spot-on that you won't be able to merge/sync the data.  You'll have to pick one DC, wipe it, and restart it one node at a time once there's a route on 7000 available AND it's using the other DCs pod-0 IP as a seed.

Comment: @Aaron thank you, about merging the data is not an issue now, we can delete the data or reconfigure the dc as we want. the main issue is that I cannot specify a different port for the other hosts connected to the cluster, something like Elasticsearch where you have http.port and http.publish_port https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#http-settings it would be perfect

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, these are the three basic attributes required for nodes to form a cluster:

- the same `cluster_name`
- inter-node network connectivity for gossip
- common seeds

For two DCs in different K8s clusters to be able to form a cluster, you'll need to setup the first DC with bi-directional TCP network connectivity enabled on gossip port `7000` between the two K8s clusters.

You will also need to make sure that the pods are configured to use a service for the seeds list in `cassandra.yaml`. This seeds service must be exposed so that it is accessible to the other K8s cluster.

Once the first DC is operational, you will need to replicate the configuration on to the second DC in the other K8s cluster such that:

- the second DC has the same `cluster_name`
- uses the same seeds service as DC1 in the seeds list of the pods
- have network connectivity to gossip on port `7000`

Ideally, the second DC also has a seeds service configured so they can be used by both DCs. Cheers!

Comment: thank you for your explanation, the only issue that I see is "open the port 7000". In kubernetes/openshift the only ways to open a port is to use nodePorts (but I already know that the port range allowed in my company are not including the port 7000, maybe I can change the port using one of the ports allowed?). The other way to expose traffic outside k8s/openshift is using a route/ingress but it means creating a  loadbalancer and a dns and the traffic will be exposed on the port 443 (at least in my company)

Comment: Your comment "port range allowed in my company are not including the port 7000" doesn't actually make sense. That's not a reason to say "it won't work". The internode port `7000` is assigned by default unless you configure nodes to communicate using another port. Cheers!

Comment: The issue is that to expose the traffic outside our Openshift Cluser we have to use what is called "an openshift route", which gives to you a dns and a loadbalancer. The only port allowed to be exposed is the port 443 and if I try to configure that port in cassandra/docker I got an error "Invalid port... priviliged port requested". I have to find a way to tell cassandra:"Listen to the port 7000 but when you try to connect to other hosts use the port 443"

Comment: If there is something like Elasticsearch where you have `http.port` and `http.publish_port`  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#http-settings it would be perfect

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `hostPort` instead of `nodePort`. I've been able to get two independent OpenShift K8s kubes connected into a single cluster, using cass-operator, but it required a bit of hijinks. Can you see this doc https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YuS0FaCKIu_Sa9XMDRSI17MqMOHqzScR6SO7XVBImz4/edit